# I've got a form filter but I also need to sort (MS Access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got an on_load sub to set the filter of a subform which liiks like this:

```
Me.TabMonths.Pages("pge" & i).Controls("frmTileSchedule" & i).Form.Filter = "[MonthNo] = " & i & " and [YearNo] = " & intYear & ""
Me.TabMonths.Pages("pge" & i).Controls("frmTileSchedule" & i).Form.FilterOn = True
```

I now also need to sort it alphabetically on a field called 'Tile', and have tried

```
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Tile ASC"
```

As well as

```
Me.TabMonths.Pages("pge" & i).Controls("frmTileSchedule" & i).Form.OrderBy = "Tile ASC"
```

But no luck with these. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to filtering:

```
Me.TabMonths.Pages("pge" & i).Controls("frmTileSchedule" & i).Form.OrderBy = "Tile ASC"
Me.TabMonths.Pages("pge" & i).Controls("frmTileSchedule" & i).Form.OrderByOn= True
```